# batch - delete last char from string

Tags: string, batch-file, batch-processing, iperf

I've got the following string out of a jSON-File:

> 39468856,

Now, I want to calculate with this numbers.. because of that, I've to remove the `,` at the end.

At this moment I use the following code:

```
for /f "skip=24 tokens=2" %%a in (text.txt) do ( 

Set %%a=%%a:~0,1%
echo %%a

SET /a b=a*2
echo %%a
@echo Uebertragen in 10s:

echo %%a bytes

)
```

The `Set %%a=%%a:~0,1%` isn't working for me.. and neither the `SET /a b=a*2` (maybe because of the `,` in it).

Please help me with this...

Thanks in advance

Comment: string manipulation doesn't work with `for` variables (`%%a`), only with "normal" variables (`%var%`) Inside a `for` block, you will have to use [delayed expansion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082): `!var!`

Comment: @Stephan, or `call set` ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without seeing the full code and the input file, these could be some of the simplest solutions.

```dos
for /f "skip=24 tokens=2" %%a in (text.txt) do for %%b in (%%a) do set /a "b=%%b*2"
echo %b%
```

This option removes the comma, that is handled as a delimiter, using a second `for` loop.

```dos
for /f "skip=24 tokens=2" %%a in (text.txt) do 2>nul set /a "b=2*%%a"
echo %b%
```

In this case, the order of the operands has been changed and the error output (the comma is still there) discarded.

If the input file data allows it, *maybe* this could be used

```dos
for /f "skip=24 tokens=2 delims=, " %%a in (text.txt) do set /a "b=%%b*2"
echo %b%
```

including the comma as a delimiter in the `for /f`, the tokenizer will discard it and the comma will not be included in the retrieved data.

In all cases, as the `echo` has been moved out of the block of code that sets the variable there is no need for delayed expansion.

But, maybe, none of this options can be used. Then your best option is to use delayed expansion

```dos
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "skip=24 tokens=2" %%a in (text.txt) do ( 
    for %%b in (%%a) do set /a "b=%%b*2"
    echo !b!
)
```

Or, with the original substring approach

```dos
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "skip=24 tokens=2" %%a in (text.txt) do ( 
    set "b=%%a"

    rem Any of these could work
    set "b=!b:~0,-1!"
    set "b=!b:,=!"

    set /a "b*=2"
    echo !b!
)
```